# Use of Python regex on multiple lines of an address

Tags: python, regex

I have an address with the following structure:

Address: Name of business

Address line #1,

Address line #2 Pincode

I created the following regex statement : `re.findall(r'Address : (.*)', text, re.MULTILINE)`

I presume that this would find all the lines from `Address:` to the 6 digit pincode.

But it only seems to be pulling the first line. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `re.MULTILINE` should be `re.DOTALL`

Comment: I shall try that @SuperStormer. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

This should work fine, unless you have an issue with spaces around the colon (which are inconsistent in your post).

```
import re

text = """
Address: Name of business
Address: line #1,
Address: line #2 Pincode
"""

for match in re.findall(r'Address: (.*)', text, re.MULTILINE):
    print(match)
```

Output:

```
Name of business
line #1,
line #2 Pincode
```

Comment: Yep so I am sorry for not being clear but there is only one address. This is the an example of the way it would show up :

Address : Nike Inc
1234 West Devon Road
Ames, Iowa 51273

I basically want it to pick up from Address: (which is the start of the entire line) till the 5 digit pincode (which would be 6 in my country).